# Phone Number selection using Twilio

Tags: sms, twilio

I want to use Twilio to send sms from India to within India. Do I have to use a US phone number to do so or can I use my own number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Customer Support here.

Unfortunately we do not have local numbers in India at this time, so the best solution is to use an American number for now.

I recommend you read through this FAQ as it contains information on some of the restrictions in place when messaging Indian numbers:

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices

Regards,
Tom